# JavaScript - use of this in Arrow function inside class

Tags: javascript, lambda, arrow-functions

Can we use this keyword inside the arrow function of the class?

```
class Student{
  constructor(name, grade){
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
  }
  need = () => {
    return this.name + " need a cricket kit";
  }
   career = () => {
    return this.need();
  }
}

const student = new Student("Raman Sharma", "7");
console.log(student.career()); //"Raman Sharma need a cricket kit"
```

Well, I know that:
MDN says: "An arrow function does not have its own this"

```
 let user = { 
        name: "GFG", 
        gfg1:() => { 
            console.log("hello " + this.name); // no 'this' binding here 
        }, 
        gfg2(){        
            console.log("Welcome to " + this.name); // 'this' binding works here 
    }   
 }; 
user.gfg1(); 
user.gfg2();
```

I think I am misunderstanding something. Can you help me out of that?

Comment: TL;DR: it's a special feature of Typescript and/or experimental feature in Babel to create a bound instance method.

Comment: can I get some reference for that?

Comment: See the duplicate, and possibly https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties.